# JavaScript - Create a table based on array of object

Tags: javascript

I have this array of object:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6937729",
        "affiliate_url": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=116db0312&aff_code=4b8685e94&campaign_unique=4b9a6d5ea",
        "availability": true,
        "brand": "SensoPRO Milano",
        "descriptionDDDD": "Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano sunt alegerea perfecta pentru a evita aparitia calcaielor crapate sau a deshidratarii pielii picioarelor! Botosii SPA sunt creati din material textil, flausat. Fiind flausati, mentin o temperatura constanta a parafinei atunci cand sunt utilizati. Folosind Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano vei obtine intretinerea picioarelor, dar vei avea parte si de momente de relaxare! ATENTIE! Acesti botosi nu au parafina inclusa, aceasta se cumpara separat!",
        "id": "6937729",
        "image_link": [
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/6/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633286.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/5/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633285.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/7/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633287.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/8/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633288.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/5/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7643575.jpg"
        ],
        "link": "https://www.kitunghii.ro/parafina-cosmetica-2/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano?utm_source=portal&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=2parale",
        "price": "19.9",
        "product type": "Epilare",
        "test_value_name1": "test_content_value1",
        "test_value_name2": "test_content_value2",
        "title": "Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-31T12:29:56.000000Z",
        "date_upd": 1665255561
    },
    {
        "_id": "6937887",
        "affiliate_url": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=5cd952501&aff_code=4b8685e94&campaign_unique=4b9a6d5ea",
        "availability": true,
        "brand": "SensoPRO Milano",
        "descriptionDDDD": "Magnet Cat Eye Dublu pentru Oja SensoPRO Milano, accesorii pentru unghii, se adreseaza in mod special ojelor permanente Magnetto pentru Cat Eye Effect, in realizarea efectului special de \"Cat Eyes\".",
        "id": "6937887",
        "image_link": [
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/4/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano~7618904.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/3/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano~7618903.jpg"
        ],
        "link": "https://www.kitunghii.ro/accesorii-manichiura/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano?utm_source=portal&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=2parale",
        "price": "9.9",
        "product type": "Accesorii Unghii",
        "test_value_name1": "test_content_value1",
        "test_value_name2": "test_content_value2",
        "title": "Magnet Cat Eye Dublu pentru Oja SensoPRO Milano",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-31T12:29:56.000000Z",
        "date_upd": 1665248423
    },
]
```

Now, I want to make a table using that data. Table **header** will be the **Object key** and **table column** value will be  corresponding header **keys value**.

**Note : this array object keys can be different in actual loop. There could 2 keys or 200 keys.**

How can I do this?

I am trying this:

```
Object.keys(response.data.data).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key)
    console.log(response.data.data[key])
})
```

I got the idea now:

```
response.data.data.forEach( ( item, key) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        console.log(key)
        console.log(item[key])
    })
});
```

Comment: What have you tried or researched?

Comment: Can you add a real example of the output you want. I don't think it's very clear from your message.

Comment: Great, you know how to loop through the keys. Now write some code that will create your table header.

Comment: I got the idea now, added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a JSON array into a table, you will first need to gather all unique keys. You can either get the keys from the first item, or get all the keys for all the items. Once you have the keys, you need to get the unique ones and sort the list.

Once you have the keys, you can build your table column headers. The table body rows can be built by iterating over the records and for each record, the keys can be used to process the table cells.

**Note:** Objects need to be serialized into JSON.

```js
const createEl = (tagName, config, parent = document.body) =>
  parent.append(Object.assign(document.createElement(tagName), config));

const main = () => {
  createEl('h2', { innerText: 'Unspecified keys' });
  document.body.append(createTable(data));

  createEl('h2', { innerText: 'Specified keys' });
  document.body.append(createTable(data, ['_id', 'title', 'availability']));
};

const createTable = (records, keys) => {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  const actualKeys = keys ?? gatherKeys(records);
  table.append(createTableHead(actualKeys));
  table.append(createTableBody(records, actualKeys));
  return table;
};

const gatherKeys = (records, firstRecordOnly = false) =>
  firstRecordOnly && records && records.length
    ? Object.keys(records[0]).sort()
    : [...new Set(records.flatMap(record => Object.keys(record)))].sort();


const createTableHead = (keys) => {
  const thead = document.createElement('thead');
  const theadRow = document.createElement('tr');
  keys.forEach(key => {
    theadRow.append(createTableColumnHeader(key));
  });
  thead.append(theadRow);
  return thead;
};

const createTableColumnHeader = (key) => {
  const th = document.createElement('th');
  th.innerText = key;
  return th;
};

const createTableBody = (records, keys) => {
  const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  records.forEach(record => {
    tbody.append(createTableRow(record, keys));
  });
  return tbody;
};

const createTableRow = (record, keys) => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  keys.forEach(key => {
    tr.append(createTableCell(record[key]));
  });
  return tr;
};

const createTableCell = (value) => {
  const td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerText = serializeValue(value)
  return td;
};

const serializeValue = (value) =>
  value && typeof value === 'object'
    ? JSON.stringify(value)
    : value;

const data = [{
  "_id": "6937729",
  "affiliate_url": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=116db0312&aff_code=4b8685e94&campaign_unique=4b9a6d5ea",
  "availability": true,
  "brand": "SensoPRO Milano",
  "descriptionDDDD": "Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano sunt alegerea perfecta pentru a evita aparitia calcaielor crapate sau a deshidratarii pielii picioarelor! Botosii SPA sunt creati din material textil, flausat. Fiind flausati, mentin o temperatura constanta a parafinei atunci cand sunt utilizati. Folosind Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano vei obtine intretinerea picioarelor, dar vei avea parte si de momente de relaxare! ATENTIE! Acesti botosi nu au parafina inclusa, aceasta se cumpara separat!",
  "id": "6937729",
  "image_link": [
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/6/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633286.jpg",
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/5/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633285.jpg",
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/7/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633287.jpg",
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/8/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633288.jpg",
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/5/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7643575.jpg"
  ],
  "link": "https://www.kitunghii.ro/parafina-cosmetica-2/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano?utm_source=portal&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=2parale",
  "price": "19.9",
  "product type": "Epilare",
  "test_value_name1": "test_content_value1",
  "test_value_name2": "test_content_value2",
  "title": "Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano",
  "updated_at": "2022-08-31T12:29:56.000000Z",
  "date_upd": 1665255561
}, {
  "_id": "6937887",
  "affiliate_url": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=5cd952501&aff_code=4b8685e94&campaign_unique=4b9a6d5ea",
  "availability": true,
  "brand": "SensoPRO Milano",
  "descriptionDDDD": "Magnet Cat Eye Dublu pentru Oja SensoPRO Milano, accesorii pentru unghii, se adreseaza in mod special ojelor permanente Magnetto pentru Cat Eye Effect, in realizarea efectului special de \"Cat Eyes\".",
  "id": "6937887",
  "image_link": [
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/4/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano~7618904.jpg",
    "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/3/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano~7618903.jpg"
  ],
  "link": "https://www.kitunghii.ro/accesorii-manichiura/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano?utm_source=portal&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=2parale",
  "price": "9.9",
  "product type": "Accesorii Unghii",
  "test_value_name1": "test_content_value1",
  "test_value_name2": "test_content_value2",
  "title": "Magnet Cat Eye Dublu pentru Oja SensoPRO Milano",
  "updated_at": "2022-08-31T12:29:56.000000Z",
  "date_upd": 1665248423
}]

main();
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.125rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead th {
  background: #DDD;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEE;
}

th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 10rem;
}
```

Comment: Can you check this code please: https://codeshare.io/78y8Zo. Using this code I can set the header but can't set the corresponse header value :(

Comment: `this.rows.push` is not setting the key or sth wrong.

Comment: I mean this: https://prnt.sc/B2dRKroizwZr